# Application build/deployment for python

Tags: python, build, setup-deployment

Just really looking to develop a good build/deployment strategy for python web applications written in mostly django/web.py. I currently only utilize setuptools to get my dependencies, but would like to see what others are doing

Answer (score 1):

We use [zc.buildout](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout) to create repeatable development and deployment setups. During development, [mr.developer](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer) is an unmissable extension.

It's important you use a versions section to pin all egg versions though to ensure your buildout is repeatable at all times. Setting the allow-picked-versions option to false will alert you to any version pins you may have overlooked.